# Populating form with data from SQL database

Tags: php, sql, database

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<option value='".$row['Current_Location']."'>".$row['Current_Location']."</option>";
}
```

I have the code above which goes through the database and checks for all the "Current_Locations" within my database it then populates the drop down menu. However, I have some data that are similar such as "Home". Therefore if there's 3 "Home" data in my database, it then display 3 "Home" in the drop down menu. Is there a way to fix this? I thought of doing an if statement maybe to break it but I'm new to PHP and not entirely sure how to approach it.

Comment: either do it on the query side, or make an if statement on the PHP side

Comment: Try to select your data `DISTINCT` e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT Current_Location ...`

Comment: @Rizier123 looked it up and it worked. Thanks fella

Answer (score 2):

You can select your data `DISTINCT` so you don't select duplicate data you can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Current_Location ...
```